# Proof that it is a ring - new operations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let {K,+,*} be commutative ring with unit. Define new operations ¤ and o so x¤y=x+y-1 and xoy=x+y-xy. Show that {K,¤,o} is a ring.

How can I show that the opeartions are closed for K? How can I show that x+y-1 belongs to K and x+y-xy belongs to K?

I manged to prove the other steps.

Comment: How do you show the operations are closed?  It is obvious that they are since the operations are defined exclusively using other operations which are known to be closed.

Comment: I understand that x+y belongs to K, but why does x+y-1 belong to k for instance?

Comment: $1$ is the notation for the unit of the original ring.  $-$ is the notation for the "additive" inverse, etc...

Comment: $x+y-1$ is the same as $(x+y)-1$. You already noted that for $x,y\in K$, $x+y\in K$. $1$ is the unit and is in $K$, so you have an element in $K$ ($x+y$) and you're subtracting an element in $K$ ($1$) from it. What can you conclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $+$ and $\cdot$ are already closed over $K.$

We begin by showing $x,y\in K$ implies $x+y-1\in K.$ Namely, if $x,y\in K,$ then we know $x+y\in K.$ Then $-1\in K$ as well, so $(x+y)+(-1)\in K$ as well.

Nowe we show $x,y\in K$ implies $x+y-xy\in K.$ Again, $x,y\in K$ implies $x+y\in K$ and $x\cdot y\in K,$ so $-x\cdot y\in K$ as well, so $(x+y)+(-xy)\in K.$